# Is it possible to run an application from my application when it's running background state?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible that my iphone application will run in background state and after some time interval it will start another program or application from my iphone.

Suppose, I want to start the camera preview after 10 minute later that will be handled from my iphone. So, my application will run in background state and it will start the camera view after 10 minutes.

Is it possible ???

Answer (score 1):

The only way to start other applications is to use the url schemes exposed by the other app. If it does not expose such scheme, you won't be able to start it.

What about scheduling such thing when you're in the background, you can register for timed local notifications that will show a popup to the user when the time has been elapsed. If the user accepts the popup, your application will get focus and CPU so you can launch also other apps.

There is another option, to get some seconds of CPU in every 10 minutes. It is called VoIP services and you can register for it in the project settings, then it'll call a callback in your app delegate when the OS decides to grant you some CPU.

Study "local notifications" and "url schemes", these are the technologies you need.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically on whether your app can do anything while in the background state, recommend watching the 2010 WWDC video "Session 105 - Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Part 1" : https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345587?i=1907522673

TL;DR: you can only finish up tasks upon entering the background. MrTJ is right about using a timed local notification, and you can also investigate Apple Push Notifications too, if a bit more work and outside the scope of your original ask.